# Theming individual menus

Tags: 7, routes, theming

Let me fully describe the problem I am trying to solve as there may be a better way of doing what I am trying to do.

On my Drupal 7 install, when a user is logged out, the Main menu shows Home / Log In and a few other links I've added. This is $primary_nav in the theme.

When a user is logged in, a Log Out link is added.

What is confusing however, is that there is still a login link in the Main menu.

My solution was to create a second menu that would replace the Log in link with a link to the user's account page when they are logged in. All other links would remain the same.

In the template, I am doing the following:

```
<?php // show different menus depending on if the user is logged in ?>
<?php if ($user->uid): ?>
<?php $menu = menu_navigation_links('user-menu'); ?>
<?php print theme('links__menu_user_menu', array('links' => $menu)); ?>
<?php else: print $primary_nav; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And this correctly shows the right menu depending on whether the use is logged in or not.

However, the styles are completely different. $primary_nav is a horizontal menu and user-menu is a vertical menu.

According to http://drupal.org/node/254940#theme-suggestions-for-menus, I should be able to create a function in my theme's template.php file and style it. However, I tried doing the following:

```
function MYTHEME_menu_tree__user_menu(&$variables) {
  echo 'Success'; exit;
}
```

But that code is not run.

So my questions are these:

1) Is this the best approach to replace Log In with a link to the user account page when the user is logged in?

2a) If so, what's the best way to get the menu styled the way I want it?

2b) If not, how can I achieve the effect listed in 1)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `user` as login path, it will visible after login.

You should replace `user` with `user/login` it will gone after login.

Also user's profile link is available in `User menu`, just edit it and change its parent menu to your `primary nav`.

Comment: So much simpler than the way I was trying to do it. Thanks!